# Return matching named table in worksheet function VBA

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

Does anyone know how to return a values in a table with:

> WorksheetFunction.Match

Or this there any other alternative function that could be used in order for it to be working.

> rowNum = WorksheetFunction.Match(sum.Range("coverage").Table, temp.Range("A1:A200"), 0)
>    'colNum = WorksheetFunction.Match(sum.Range("Header").Value, temp.Range("CoverageT"), 0)

Above I tried to use WorksheetFunction to get it to work but that was a fail. I named tables 'coverage and 'header to get it to function but I did not succeed.

I hope my problem is clear enough to get some help!
If it's not clear enough please leave a comment!

Comment: Yeah, it's unclear to me as to what exactly are you trying. Can you perhaps explain it with screenshots?

Comment: I cannot add a screenshot yet as I need 10 reputation badges but I will be more clear about the issue I am currently facing. I want to use "workSheetfunction.Match" to be able to match the table called 'coverage" in the worksheet called "summary" with the table that was uploaded through the web from the columns "A1: A200". @SiddharthRout  I have attached in another comment a fuller version of my code

Comment: end with @SiddharthRout

Comment: upload the screen shot somewhere .. n provide the link

Comment: <https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-uYox0RzKgy4/UlP9tVElSVI/AAAAAAAAAEQ/4Z56u_YocQQ/w1598-h649-no/workfunction.PNG><https://plus.google.com/u/0/112885617103885166656/posts> <https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-fl2I2vw-1Y4/UlP6WL7nKLI/AAAAAAAAADQ/t_zwe_z6Sao/w1598-h843-no/workfunction1.PNG>

Comment: @SiddharthRout the 2 image should be working fine now

Comment: @SathishK the 2nd picture has now being uloaded

Comment: Sorry was out. The screenshot that you gave is for the code. Update your question with the code and give a link of your worksheet here so that we can upload it. Also delete the comments with the code as they don't make any sense there :)

Comment: Sorry I thought I replied back but I just realised I did not, I cannot put a link to the spreadsheet simply because there are real world data but I did not found a solution to what I was trying to achieve. @SathishK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WorksheetFunction.Match gets you the relative position of a value in a single column range or a single row range. If your item is third in the list it returns 3.

If you want the value from a table use WorksheetFunction.VLookup. You are looking up your item in the first column of a table or range. You specify which column you want the value from and it will return the cell value from the matching row.

Or use HLookup for a transposed table.

Try this if you really want to use Match:

```
dim KeyValue as string
KeyValue = "my item"

Dim rowNum as Variant
If Not VBA.IsError(Application.Match(KeyValue, temp.Range("A1:A200"), 0)) Then
    rowNum = Application.Match(KeyValue, temp.Range("A1:A200"), 0)
End If
```

Try this if you want a vlookup:

```
Dim RetVal As Variant
Dim KeyValue As String 'or integer or date as appropriate
Dim LookupTable As Range
Dim ColumnNumber As Integer

KeyValue = "myItem"
LookupTable = Range("A1:A200")
ColumnNumber = 2
RetVal = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(KeyValue, LookupTable, ColumnNumber, False)
```